# How to prevent deletion of the <html> tag in Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have code like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
doc.to_html
```

and an HTML fragment which will be parsed:

```
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    <html>
        <p>
            qwerty
        </p>
    </html>
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
```

Nokogiri deletes the `<html>` `</html>` tags in the `<code>` block. How can I prevent this behavior?

**UPDATE:**

[the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) proposed solution, pre parse fragment of html and escape all html in code block

Here some code, it's not beautiful so if you want suggest another solution please post a comment

```
html.gsub!(/<code\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/code>/m) do |x|
  "<code>#{CGI.escapeHTML($1)}</code>"
end
```

Thanks [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML is invalid. I used this to test it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    <html>
        <p>
            qwerty
        </p>
    </html>
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
EOT

puts doc.errors
```

After parsing a document, Nokogiri will populate the `errors` array with a list of errors it found during parsing. In the case of your HTML, `doc.errors` contains:

```
htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag
```

The reason is that, inside the `<code>` block, the tags are not HTML encoded as they should be.

Convert it using HTML entities to:

```
&lt;html&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        qwerty
    &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

And it will work.

Nokogiri is a XML/HTML parser, and it attempts to fix errors in the markup to allow you, the programmer, to have a good chance of using the document. In this case, because the `<html>` block is in the wrong place, it removes the tags. Nokogiri wouldn't care if the tags were encoded, because, at that point, they're simply text, not tags.

---

EDIT:

> I'll try pre parse with gsub and convert html in code block

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    <html>
        <p>
            qwerty
        </p>
    </html>
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html.gsub(%r[<(/?)html>], '&lt;\1html&gt;'))

puts doc.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    &lt;html&gt;
        <p>
            qwerty
        </p>
    &lt;/html&gt;
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
```

---

EDIT:

This will process the `<html>` tag prior to parsing, so Nokogiri can load the `<code>` block unscathed. It then finds the `<code>` block, unescapes the encoded `<html>` start and end tags, then inserts the resulting text into the `<code>` block as its content. Because it is inserted as content, when Nokogiri renders the DOM as HTML the text is reencoded as entities where necessary:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    <html>
        <p>
            qwerty
        </p>
    </html>
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html.gsub(%r[<(/?)html>], '&lt;\1html&gt;'))

code = doc.at('code')
code.content = CGI::unescapeHTML(code.inner_html)

puts doc.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
<p>some paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
<code>
    &lt;html&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;
            qwerty
        &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
</code>
<p>some other paragraph</p>
<a href="https://url...com"><span style="color: #a5a5a5;"><i>qwerty</i></span> ytrewq </a>
```

Comment: It's exactly what i wont to do in next steps in my code.
<code>CGI.escapeHTML(node.inner_html) if node.name.downcase == "code"</code>

But i lost < html > tag in output, becouse Nokogiri delete it.

Comment: That's right. Nokogiri tries to make sense of it, and can't. You have to do the fix-up before Nokogiri sees it.

Comment: Tnx. I'll try pre parse with gsub and convert html in code block.
Tnx you!

Comment: You solution work but I'm need escape all HTML in code block not only < html > tag.
CGI.escapeHTML(node.inner_html) broke your pre parsed content with html.gsub.

Maybe you can tell me some regexp gsub all content in < code > tag?

Like http://pastebin.com/BRdZhd4D but it's escape along with < code > </ code > but i need only content of block.
Tnx

Comment: You can't use `node.inner_html` because Nokogiri has already removed the `<html>` tag at that point. You have to process the contents prior to passing it to Nokogiri, and then you can find the `<code>` tag and massage its contents. The best answer is that wherever you are getting the HTML from needs to fix it because they are generating bad HTML.

Comment: @user1190420, check the added example.